# Property 'href' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DeliveryInfoProps'

Tags: typescript, next.js, storybook

I have 2 component inside the template, they receives the `{...args}` but in one component I what to have `href` and another I do not want to have `href` so in one component is **link** in another is **text**.

When I put in another component `<DeliveryInfoComponent {...args} href="textLink" />` the rooro show me  ***Property 'href' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DeliveryInfoProps'*** but `href` is in the interface in `bottomTextProps`.

**.stories**

```
const Template: StoryType<DeliveryInfoProps> = (args) => (
  <>
    <DeliveryInfoComponent {...args} />
    <DeliveryInfoComponent {...args} href="textLink" />
  </>
);

export const DeliveryInfo = Template.bind({});

DeliveryInfo.args = {
  heading: 'heading4',
  body: 'body',
  bodyHeading: 'heading4',
  icon: <PostnlIcon />,
  bottomTextProps: {
    title: 'title',
    href: 'text',
  },
};
```

**.tsx**

```
export interface DeliveryInfoProps {
  heading: string;
  body: string;
  bodyHeading: string;
  icon: ReactNode;
  bottomTextProps: {
    title: string;
    href?: string;
  };
}

const DeliveryInfo = ({ heading, body, bodyHeading, icon, bottomTextProps }: DeliveryInfoProps) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const { title, href } = bottomTextProps;

  const bottomContent = useMemo(() => {
    if (href) {
      return (
        <Text type="body" color="secondary" removeGutter href={href} component={NextComposed}>
          {title}
        </Text>
      );
    }
    return (
      <Text type="body" color="secondary" removeGutter>
        {title}
      </Text>
    );
  }, [href, title]);
```

Comment: The `href` is contained within the `bottomTextProps` prop, but is not a direct prop of your `DeliveryInfo` component so you can't pass it as `<DeliveryInfoComponent {...args} href="textLink" />`.

Comment: how can i di it with in <DeliveryInfoComponent {...args} component